# Actor that creates othe Actors of the same type

Tags: akka, actor

I'm very new to Akka. I am considering using it in a Java project and I ran into a situation where an Actor can tell messages to other n Actors, everyone of them of the same type. It's kinda like recursion.

Is this considered bad practice? Is this a sign of a design flaw?

Details with best practices to achieve such results are welcome.

Comment: I answered the question, but I'll wait for other views before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found out by Carl Hewitt, the inventor of the [Actor Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Hewitt#Actor_model) himself, in [an introductionary talk about actors given to channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Hewitt-Meijer-and-Szyperski-The-Actor-Model-everything-you-wanted-to-know-but-were-afraid-to-ask), at 2:16:

> (...) in order to come in systems, they [the Actors] have to have
>   addresses, so that one actor can send a message to another actor, and
>   there's no reason an actor like Factorial can't have an address for
>   itself, so that's the way you implement recursion (...)